# Reference to a non shared member requires an object reference

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have added one class under namespace BusinessLogics.
I have inherited System.Web.UI.Page to class and showing error as 'end expected' in 
System.Web.UI.Page

```
Namespace BusinessLogics
    Public Class BllUploadImages Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    End Class
End Namespace
```

How can i remove my error.Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

The `Server` property is an instance property of the `Page` class, so you need a `Page` instance in order to access it. There are a couple of different ways for you to solve this.

It looks like `objDesign` is of a type that inherits `System.Web.UI.Page`. Perhaps you can use that instance to invoke the `MapPath` method:

```
serverPath = objDesign.Server.MapPath(".") + "\"
```

One other approach is to fetch the current [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) object and use the [`Server`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.server.aspx) property of that object:

```
serverPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "\"
```